# Find & Replace text in a email (oft or msg)

Tags: vb.net

Thankyou for stopping by to look at my question.

I’m trying to replace text in an email (oft or msg).

I’m trying to find.

@@TEST1@@ and replace with textbox1.text

@@TEST2@@ and replace with textbox2.text

@@TEST3@@ and replace with textbox3.text

I have found the following to open the email template and this works a treat.

```
 Dim Outl As Object
    Outl = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    If Outl IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim omsg As Object
        omsg = Outl.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Testing\EmailSerials.oft")
        omsg.To = "yusuf@hotmail.com"
        omsg.subject = "Hello, Please find your Software"
        omsg.Display(True) 
    End If
```

i'm new at this so any help or examples would be great.

Manty thanks
James

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [[MailItem].Body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem) and [String.Replace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

I worked on the assumption that the OFT file had content you wish to replace. I also took the opportunity to replace the VB6 code with VB.Net version.

Add a reference to:

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook

And, also add this to the top of the file:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop
```

And then the code to replace the text you are wanting to replace

```
    Dim Outl As New Outlook.Application

    If Outl IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim omsg As Outlook.MailItem = CType(Outl.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Testing\EmailSerials.oft"), Outlook.MailItem)
        omsg.To = "yusuf@hotmail.com"
        omsg.subject = "Hello, Please find your Software"

        omsg.Body = omsg.Body.Replace("@@TEST1@@", textbox1.text)
        omsg.Body = omsg.Body.Replace("@@TEST2@@", textbox2.text)
        omsg.Body = omsg.Body.Replace("@@TEST3@@", textbox3.text)

        omsg.Display(True)
    End If
```